# Chrome extension inline js update

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to update my inline code to be external for the new Chrome extension manifest.

My old code is:

```
<input id="importbutton" type="file" onchange="dataImport(this.files);">
```

My new code is, except it isn't working - maybe someone can help me debug this?

```
$('#importbutton').bind('onchange', function() {
    var myimport = $('#importbutton').val();
    dataImport(myimport.files);
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is interpreting "this" part as it looks for the same thing and then files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `change` method (can't test right now, so apologies if it crashes and burns :) ):

```
$('#importbutton').change(function(e) {
    var myimport = $(this).val();
    dataImport(myimport.files);
});
```